# Having issues with OnPlatform selection for UWP in Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Good time of day to all. I am working on Xamarin.Forms project, including iOS, Android and UWP parts. My project requires usage of different custom fonts, accessible for all devices. So I added custom fonts and I am selecting them with

```
string fontName = Device.OnPlatform(
                 "RoundedLEDBoard-7",
                 "rounded_led_board-7.ttf#Rounded LED Board-7",
                 @"Assets\Fonts\rounded_led_board-7.ttf#Rounded LED Board-7");
```

Font names and locations are correct.

On the modeling stage I used a single page solution, to prototype some of the basic functionality. All worked exactly as expected on all three platforms, both emulators and real test devices. However, after adding navigation capabilities and changing App.xaml.cs from

```
MainPage = new Different_fonts.MainPage();
```

to

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Different_fonts.MainPage());
```

I have discovered, that the font is not loaded (or displayed?) in UWP part of the project. Android and iOS parts look as expected. Complete re-build of the entire solution did not help. Does any one know where the problem is and what is the cure remedy?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found quite an odd bug! I am also seeing this issue with a sample project using Forms 2.3.3. As you mentioned, iOS and Android don't experience this issue so this should work on UWP as well.

Unfortunately I don't have a workaround for this in the meantime, but I've filed [a bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51427) so we can look into this.

Comment: Ahh, glad I could help. Hopefully, we will see this fixed sometimes reasonably soon. :)